# В чем преимущество MVC

Tags: mvc, проектирование

Хочу услышать плюсы MVC паттерна. Варианты удобно, красиво не подходят. Как работает паттерн Model-View-Controller известно. Но в чем явные преимущества?

Comment: я думаю вы не знаете как он работает, иначе вам были бы известны его преимущества

Comment: А если я хочу минусы написать

Comment: Пишите и минусы )

Comment: ampawd Да я сам в шоке, это как два года работать, а потом не работать лопатой и забыть зачем она нужна

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В MVC четко разделена логика приложения, а это, в свою очередь, на много упрощает работу над большими проектами.

Плюсом будет так же:
 1) Удобство выводить разные представления (view) для разных типов устройств, при этом пользуясь одними и теми же данными;
 2) Облегчается поддержка и тестирование кода.

Comment: 3) повторное использование кода

Comment: Это не только привелегия mvc. Ответ не устроил ( "Варианты удобно, красиво не подходят." 1й пункт хороший ответ

Comment: @user2455111 , тогда извините, больше преимуществ не нашел. А чего Вы ожидали от MVC?

Comment: хз, я его юзал 2 года, но достойных плюсов кроме первого так и не вижу, и на собеседовании этот вопрос и завалил. А именно 1)Удобство выводить разные представления (view) для разных типов устройств, при этом пользуясь одними и теми же данными; Спасибо!

Comment: @user2455111 тогда, возможно, следовало задать этот вопрос непосредственно у проводящего человека собеседования, а не здесь?)

Comment: я ответ на вопрос получил, плюса поставить не могу, т.к. рейтинга нет. Я же написал, спасибо! Уверен, что он имел ввиду "выводить разные представления (view) для разных типов устройств" возможно и с моделями та же ситуация. Но не знаю входит ли это в концепцию mvc или тут уже orm играет роль

Answer (score 3):

Тут как раз вариант удобно и красиво, как и со всеми паттернами к стати. Деление ролей по MVC красиво и удобно потому, что стратегически выгодно в больших проектах с насыщенным графическим интерфейсом. Оно, скажем так, отвечает тому как видит систему разработчик. Позволяет хорошо локализовать изменения в этих отдельных сущностях так, что вероятность их одновременного изменения ниже. Давайте на вскидку рассмотрим основные причины изменений:

1. Изменение структуры данных - больше всех поменяется модель, котроллер меньше, а представление возможно совсем не придется менять.
2. Изменение логики интерфейса - больше меняется представление, потом контроллер, модель еще меньше.
3. Исправление ошибок - прежде всего их проще найти, во-вторых упрощается тестирование.
4. Большие структурные изменения - их становится проще спланировать, разбить на этапы.

Проект становится более управляемым и предсказуемым, а это одна из основных целей проектирования.

Comment: Исправление ошибок - прежде всего их проще найти, во-вторых упрощается тестирование. Каким образом упрощается тестирование?

Comment: @user2455111 Тем что его можно автоматизировать с помощью написания тестов.

Comment: Изменение логики интерфейса чаще всего будет вызвано изменением логики приложения в целом, и тут наверняка в первую очередь будет изменяться доменная модель. Изменяется структура данных -> у контроллера автоматом меняется ввод, и он меняется не меньше, чем модель.

Answer (score 3):

`mvc` - создана для одного, вынести на разные слои логику приложения и то что лучше всего называть ассеты.

Но прежде всего стоит обратится к корням и понять `ареал` в котором эта `парадигма` или как ещё часто говорят `мультипаттерн` был взращен.

Концепция была описана **Трюгве Реенскаугом** в **1979** для языка `Smalltalk`...

Сделаю отступление и позволю себе предположить, что `php` или `html > css > js` разработчик пробежав по предыдущему предложению обратит внимания лишь на странное название старого языка `Smalltalk` и продолжит читать концепцию даже не догадываясь что он не сможет её понять в полной мере!

`Smalltalk` это язык на котором пишут и сервер и клиент, у него нет разделения на клиент ( как например `html`, `css`, `js`) и сервер ( `php`, `python`, `ruby` ). Вы должны представить что чтобы создать кнопку нужно лишь создать её объект. А что такое кнопка? Это и картинка и логика смены скина и события. И все это уже инкапсулировано в объекте кнопка. Это как сегодня `html`, `css`, `js` вместе взятое.

И вот когда говорят что `mvc` разделяет логику, то не имееют ввиду разделить кнопку, а имеется ввиду разделение компонентов и логики управления этими компонентами. то есть `mvc` в её первоисточнике, это правило для приложения, а не для компонента.

Но время нам показывает, как не понимая слова человека который пишет на `Smalltalk`, программисты научились разбивать на составные все, включая компоненты. Хорошо это или плохо сказать сложно. Сегодня говоря о клиент-серверном приложении, мы предполагаем `mvc` или `mvvm` на клиенте и `mvp` на сервере, но в первоисточнике понятия клиент не было, было представление. представьте что браузер это представление, а сервер это модель. Как это было бы сказать сложно, единственное о чем можно догадаться сегодня, что приложения тех лет и сегодняшних отличаются. Ну какие приложения были в 60х? Математические и наверное ещё раз математические, браузеров наверное даже не было.

Так вот, возвращаясь к `mvc`.. Основная польза от него в экономической стратегии. То есть при создании приложений которые будут развиваться и на частях которого будут создаваться приложения в будущем. Ведь сегодняшние приложения по большей части пишутся под конкретную задачу.
Взять обычный сайт, его написали и забыли, нет шансов что его будут рефакторить. Или например взять большую игру, где искусственный интеллект будет использоваться из игры к игре.

Или вспомнить правило, что логика приложения должны находится в модели. а есть ещё не гласное правило что игра или любое приложение это и есть модель. В таком случаи модель всегда одна и та же, а меняются только представления. В лучших традициях это модель которая может полноценно функционировать без других элементов. так я смогу написать морской бой для 2D и для 3D и съэкономить на программистах.

Всё, других плюсов у этой парадигмы нет и они даже не закладывались.

И закончить стоит тем, что `mvc` не последний отрог - не является единым монолитным архитектурным решением. Эта парадигма, как я сказал ранее, является связующей частью и её абсолютно безразлично что связывать. Это не дом, это каркас приложения. А в качестве стен и потолков можно использовать что угодно, так же как и более маленькие `mvc`.

Comment: Про компонентные тенденции очень спорно, скорее тенденции идут в сторону фреймверков/библиотек. Компоненты не оправдали ожиданий. И все-таки, в чем преимущество MVC?

Comment: @Cerbo, но по сути их ещё и нет.. А фраймворки разве не развиваются в сторону компонентов? У реакта - компоненты, у ангуляра 1 и 2 - тоже компоненты. пройдет ещё не мало времени, прежде чем поймут почему архитектура клиентских и серверных приложений не такие гладкие как обещали книги. Все дело в том что в оригинале клиент был просто представлением, а модель сервером. Это если одним предложением.
А вэб компоненты, настоящие, нативные, ещё вроде в одном браузере поддерживаются и то не в полную меру.

Comment: У нас с вами видимо разные компоненты. Идея компонентов была в повторном использовании кода (как и всегда впрочем), то есть идеологи говорили буквально - вот вы сделали компонент, решили задачу, а потом его в другое место "вставили" не меняя и все задача решена. Так вот, оказалось что в другое место компоненты "вставляются" с большим трудом! Потому что в другом месте решается другая задача и окружение там другое.

Comment: Вот и выходит что, чтобы компонент "вставился" в другое место он должен быть  заранее для этого места спроектирован и реализован. Но таким образом мы возвращаемся к библиотекам/фреймверкам - они более правильное решение. Компоненты же периодически проскакивают, но не потому что их идея хороша, а потому что задача удобная попадается.

Comment: @Cerbo, то что Вы описываете скорее всего элементы. Компонент это как раз объект который должен быть переиспользован. Он инкапсулирует в себе логику и представление. В понятии вэб компонентов, это как раз присутствует, ведь они имеют свою область видимости для css и для js. 
Вот лично у ангуляра и у реакта компоненты очень даже переиспользуются, что ещё сказать :)

Comment: @Cerbo а вот не надо строить мега-компоненты решающие все и сразу. Компонент должен решать одну, четко описанную, не изменяющуюся со временем  и относительно атомарную задачу, которая может входить в множество более крупных задач. Если не пытаться сделать кнопку которая и в базу залезет, и морду обновит, и за пивом сбегает, то все будет отлично.

Comment: @OlmerDale вы правда тоже перегнули с "Очень крупными проектами", польза есть и для небольших проектов с логикой средней сложности и заметная польза

Comment: @OlmerDale А кто вам сказал что речь идет о вебе, вопрос задан без привязки к технологиям. Компонентный подход имел целью создание улучшенного ООП, о вебе не было и речи.

Comment: @rdorn Вы говорите то же что и я, чтобы компонент был "вставляемым" он должен заранее для этого проектироваться. То есть от куда вы узнаете за каким пивом вам придется бегать, а за каким нет. Только если вам заранее об этом не расскажут и не покажут, понимаете. Но бывает пиво простое, не требующее объяснений и одинаковым способом везде употребляемое.

Comment: @Cerbo сам ответ вне контекста, о о mvc. На примере компонентов я пытался объяснил разницу между понятием компонент того времени и этого, но я убрал это предложение чтобы не смущать. Про ОЧЕНЬ большие не уверен что не прав. Польза, именно преимущество заметно только на больших, как например игры. Но понимаете, у всех разное понятие приложения и я не знаю как их сравнивать кого-то не обидев, по этому сокращу до любых.

Comment: @OlmerDale на больших более заметно. потому что выражается в реальных суммах денег, а на всех остальных. только в нервах и ночах разработчика =)

Comment: @rdorn - переписал 

Так вот, возвращаясь к mvc.. Польза от него есть в очень больших приложениях ( под большими приложениями я подразумеваю те, части которого будут использоваться при создании других приложений. Ведь рассудите сами, если я напишу приложение и забуду, то какая разница как он написан, если в нем самом ничего менять не буду и его части переиспользовать тоже не буду? Вот что я имею ввиду под "большим проектом" ).

Comment: @OlmerDale ок, убедили, формулировку можно вылизывать долго, но все равно найдется тот, кого она не устроит.

Comment: гнаться за обязательным использованием паттернов вроде mvc на мой взгляд не всегда целесобразно, ведь если вернуться к искомой задаче которая она решает, а основное у неё это облегчение поддержки кода и независимость логических частей приложения, то всего этого можно а иногда даже нужно добиваться своими методами, реализация которых разнится от проекта к проекту. Итог - система с спроектирована относительно хорошо только тогда, когда она решает глобально поставленную задачу, а делает она это при помощи mvc или нет - уже второстепенно