# Обновление блока со случайными элементами

Tags: php, ajax

В классе есть функция.При обновлении страницы элементы меняются.
Не могу понять что именно обновляется: таблица, массив или цикл,
что бы реализовать обновление элементов без перезагрузки.
И как это можно зделать.Спасибо.

Функция и Блок

```
protected function getRandomuser() {
$randomuser = $this->user->getRandomElement(3);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($randomuser); $i++) {
    $sr["name"] = $randomuser[$i]["login"];
    $sr["link"] = $this->config->address."?view=userdata&amp;login=".$sr["name"];
    $sr["avatar"] = $this->getAvatar($sr["name"]);
    $text .= $this->getReplaceTemplate($sr, "userread");
    }
return $text;
}



<div class="userread">
    <img src="%avatar%" alt="avatar" class="featured" />    
    <a class="name" href="%link%">%name%</a>    
</div>
```

---

```
<?php

 $myObj = new Modules();

 return $myObj->getRandomuser();

 ?>

 Но вместо элементов выходят ошибка
```

> Неустранимая ошибка: «Модули» не найдены в /home/shamil/domains/mrcloyd.ru/public_html/lib/get_random_user.php в строке 3
>   Fatal error: Class 'Modules' not found in /home/shamil/domains/mrcloyd.ru/public_html/lib/get_random_user.php on line 3

Чего-то нет

---

```
<?php

 $myObj = new Modules();

 return $myObj->getRandomuser();

 ?>
```

---

Класс где находится функция.Помогите составить код.

```
<?php

    abstract class Modules {

protected $config;
protected $user;
protected $message;
protected $banner;
protected $data;
protected $user_info;
protected $friend;
protected $twitt;

public function __construct($db) {
    session_start();
    $this->config = new Config();
    $this->user = new User($db);
    $this->message = new Message();
    $this->banner = new Banner($db);
    $this->friend = new Friend($db);
    $this->twitt = new Twitt($db);
    $this->data = $this->secureData($_GET);
    $this->user_info = $this->getUser();
}

public function getRandomuser() {
    $randomuser = $this->user->getRandomElement(3);
    foreach ($randomuser as $row) {
        $sr["name"] = $row["login"];
        $sr["link"] = $this->config->address."?view=userdata&amp;login=".$sr["name"];
        $sr["avatar"] = $this->getAvatar($sr["name"]);
        $text .= $this->getReplaceTemplate($sr, "userread");
    }
    $new_sr["items"] = $text;
    return $this->getReplaceTemplate($new_sr, "userreads"); 
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Используйте AJAX для обновления данных и на js/jquery обновляйте данные в элементе без перезагрузки страницы. Что Вы сделали в этом направлении?

Comment: Данные брать из цикла?

Comment: Да, и цикл `for` можете заменить на `foreach`, `for` Вам тут не нужен особо

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разбираться:

*PHP* - интерпретируемый язык программирования, который выполняется **только** на стороне сервера.

Он работает следующим образом - на сервер приходит [*HTTP-запрос*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) - *PHP* его принимает, обрабатывает определенным образом (выполняется Ваш скрипт) и возвращается определенный результат (если Вы пишите веб-сайты, то это будет *HTML* код, но ведь на PHP можно же и [API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)).

Следовательно, PHP-код **не может** возвращать Вам результат **без** перезагрузки страницы!

Но, к счастью, существует технология [*AJAX*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) которая позволяет выполнить серверные скрипты (это не обязательно *PHP-скрипты*) и вернуть результат *динамически* (без перезагрузки страницы).

А теперь приступим к решению Вашего вопроса:

Пускай у Вас есть *PHP-скрипт* с названием `get_random_user.php` со следующим содержимым:

**get_random_user.php**:

```
<?php
$class = new Class(); //тот класс, в котором Ваша приведенная выше функция
return $class->getRandomuser(); //только ее нужно будет сделать public!
```

Теперь, следует на *frontend* части Вашего сайта (`html`) написать *JS* скрипт, который будет "подменять" результат в нужном блоке:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/path/to/get_random_user.php"
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    $('.userread').html(msg);
  });
```

Тут есть несколько нюансов, которые Вам следует учесть в своей программе:

1. При таком *JS-коде*, результат выполнения Вашего *PHP-скрипта* должен быть в виде *HTML-кода*.
2. Тот *JS-код*, что я привел использует библиотеку [*JQuery*](https://jquery.com/) и ее ф-ю [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), следовательно, Вам нужно будет на "клиентской" части его подключить.

Если Вы используете в свой работе какой-либо [фреймворк](https://kultprosvet.net/ru/blog/10-luchshih-php-freymvorkov-dlya-veb-proektov) (напр. [Laravel](https://laravel.ru/) или [Yii](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/)), которые работают по шаблону [*MVC*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), то путь к Вашему скрипту (`url:` в *Ajax* функци) может иметь вид `http://site.local/path/to/controller/action`

Вообще, хорошей практикой в написании сайтов (да и многих других приложений на других языках) считается использование шаблона *MVC*. Во многих компаниях работают по этому шаблону. И чем раньше Вы его освоите и начнете использовать тем быстрее Вы вырастите как разработчик.

Преимущества шаблона MVC обсуждались в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575744/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-mvc) вопросе.

Comment: @shamilshakirov так Вы не комментарии правьте, а сам вопрос, там есть кнопка "править"

Comment: @shamilshakirov все верно, ведь я Вам написал примерный вариант действий, а вы уже должны переварить написанное и исправить под Ваши нужды ;)

Comment: @shamilshakirov сделайте `require` данного класса - `require 'path/to/class/Modules';`

Comment: @shamilshakirov Вы не понимаете примитивных, основных конструкций языка, я рекомендую Вам для начала почитать об ООП-конструкциях в PHP, а потом уже писать код... Вы действительно не можете инстанцировать (создать объект) абстрактного класса...

Comment: @shamilshakirov пример Вам не поможет, Вам нужна теория, а потом уже переходить к примерам.
`Нельзя создать объект класса, объявленного как abstract`

Comment: @shamilshakirov унаследуйтесь от абстрактного класса...